# Remove Duplicates from my collection in meteorjs app && render the recent score of each player

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections

I am working on a Meteorjs application which is using MongoDB in back end. In my collection there are some a lot of duplicates data like ( just an example)

```
{name:'A',score: 2, date: 4456546}
{name:'A',score:33, date:3453454}
{name:'A',score:34, date: 3453}
{name:'A',score:0, date: 12334}
{name:'B',score: 2, date: 4456546}
{name:'B',score:33, date:3453454}
{name:'B',score:34, date: 3453}
{name:'B',score:0, date: 12334}
{name:'C',score: 2, date: 4456546}
{name:'C',score:33, date:3453454}
{name:'C',score:34, date: 3453}
{name:'C',score:0, date: 12334}
```

I want to copy all this collection on an array, remove duplicates names and save only the name and the recent score of each player, like this for example

```
{name:'A',score: 2, date: 4456546}
{name:'B',score: 2, date: 4456546}
{name:'C',score: 2, date: 4456546}
```

for this I try $puch with update method but does not work;

have you any idea how to solve this??
thak's for help

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do but you can use underscore's [uniq function](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) to find unique values. In the example below I've used sort to sort the values highest date to lowest. Next I've used the uniq function with a iteratee function which returns the name as the value to check for uniqueness.

```
var allScores = [
    {name:'A',score: 2, date: 4456546},
    {name:'A',score:33, date:3453454},
    {name:'A',score:34, date: 3453},
    {name:'A',score:0, date: 12334},
    {name:'B',score:34, date: 3453},
    {name:'B',score:0, date: 12334},
    {name:'B',score: 2, date: 4456546},
    {name:'B',score:33, date:3453454},
    {name:'C',score:33, date:3453454},
    {name:'C',score: 2, date: 4456546},
    {name:'C',score:34, date: 3453},
    {name:'C',score:0, date: 12334}
];

var latestScores = _(allScores).chain().sort(function(a,b){return (b.date - a.date)}).uniq(function (x){ return x.name }).value();

// latestScores equals [{name:'A',score: 2, date: 4456546},{name:'B',score: 2, date: 4456546},{name:'C',score: 2, date: 4456546}]
```

You'd have to deal with updating the database yourself. Best to make a backup first.